# How to fetch those rows where all values are same in mysql

Tags: mysql, t-sql

I have a table:

```
Unique Value        Remarks
URTA-144            ACC
URTA-144            ADD
URTA-144            ADT
URTA-145            ALL
URTA-145            ALL
URTA-145            ALL
```

I want to fetch those rows where for each distinct `Unique Value` I have same value in `Remarks`.

For Example:

```
Unique Value
URTA-145
```

Comment: Flagged as 'to be moved on dba.stackexchange'

Comment: @Strawberry I think is much more a databaase question than a programming question so yes, i'll definetly move this to dba

Comment: @Strawberry Can you explain me why?... we're all here to learn something.

Comment: @Strawberry thank you for explanation.

Comment: The sample data set is not adequately exhaustive to properly explain the nature of the problem. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
create table Tbl(UniqueValue char(8), Remarks char(3));
insert into Tbl values
('URTA-144', 'ACC'),
('URTA-144', 'ADD'),
('URTA-144', 'ADT'),
('URTA-145', 'ALL'),
('URTA-145', 'ALL'),
('URTA-145', 'ALL');

select UniqueValue from Tbl
group by UniqueValue
having count(distinct Remarks) = 1;
```